# How to get updated values from db table in the same hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Result table. I am fetching a result row using result_id and then using result details.

I am updating some of the values of result table:

```
try {
        Result instance = (Result) getTransactionSession().get("com.xxx.Result", id); //$NON-NLS-1$
        commit();

        if (instance == null) {
            ResultHome.log.debug("get successful, no instance found"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } else {
            updateResultStepsSequence(id, instance);
            ResultHome.log.debug("get successful, instance found"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        ResultHome.log.error("get failed", re); //$NON-NLS-1$
        rollback();
        throw re;
    }
```

And

```
private void updateResultStepsSequence(long resultId, Result resultInstance) {
    if (resultInstance.getStepCount() > 0) {
        List<ResultStep> resultSteps = resultInstance.getResultSteps();
        if (resultSteps != null && !resultSteps.isEmpty() && (resultSteps.get(0).getDurationSum() == 0)) {
            try {
                Session session = SessionFactoryProvider.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                Query query = session.getNamedQuery("updateResultStepSequence").setLong("result_id", //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
                        resultId);
                query.executeUpdate();
                commit();
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                ResultHome.log.error("Query execution failed", re); //$NON-NLS-1$
                rollback();
                throw re;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After executing the updateResultStepsSequence() method, I can see that the table is getting updated, but the instance object is still holding the old values prior to the DB update.

How can I get the updated values from the table?
I tried creating a new session, updating the table and closing the newly created session.

With this approach I am able to get the latest updated values from the table.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Session.refresh()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method can be used to fetch the latest state from the database:

```
session.refresh(instance)
```